# What does tight feedback loop mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does creating a tight feedback loop mean ? I often see it in context of emails:

> You can also get feedback on your personal attempts, creating a tight
>   feedback loop.

Comment: -1 Please show the result of your research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feedback loop (from [RJMetrics](http://info.rjmetrics.com/blog/bid/53865/Feedback-loops-tight-ones-interface-design-business-management-tickling)):

[image: Example feedback loop]

In many such loops, there can be some considerable delay before each stage is apparent — you might make a decision which it takes a couple of days to put into action and another week to evaluate. **A tight feedback loop makes the time for each arrow very short.**

In the context of

> You can also get feedback on your personal attempts, creating a tight feedback loop.

it means that your attempt is evaluated very quickly, the results of that evaluation are communicated to you and you can [probably] make another attempt; and all of that happens in one session.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you get feedback quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Reads like marketing jibe to me. In that case it would mean "you get feedback." As in more filler, because the email was already mentioned.

Comment: I'd say *[jive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jive#Noun)* (sense 3, “hipster jargon”) rather than  *[jibe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jibe)* (“jeer or taunt”) in a marketing context.